# PineScript Почему request.security() работает не так, как ожидается?

Tags: pinescript

Я пытаюсь получить последние 5 баров с 1D, находясь на 5 (5 минут). Почему код работает на 1D, но не работает на более низких таймфреймах? Похоже, что [dh, dl] на младших ТФ содержит информацию только о текущем дневном баре.

```
[dh,dl] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [high,low], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
if barstate.isrealtime
    log.info("==============")
    log.info(str.tostring( dh[0] ))
    log.info(str.tostring( dh[1] ))
    log.info(str.tostring( dh[2] ))
    log.info(str.tostring( dh[3] ))
    log.info(str.tostring( dh[4] ))
```

Если запустить этот код на 1D, то все работает как ожидается:

```
[2024-03-28T14:47:27.614+03:00]: 1.08278
[2024-03-28T14:47:27.614+03:00]: 1.0839
[2024-03-28T14:47:27.614+03:00]: 1.08643
[2024-03-28T14:47:27.614+03:00]: 1.08424
[2024-03-28T14:47:27.614+03:00]: 1.0868
```

Но если я запускаю его на 5 (5 минут), то получаю серию dh, которая заполнена значением HIGH текущего дня:

```
[2024-03-28T14:49:22.420+03:00]: 1.08278
[2024-03-28T14:49:22.420+03:00]: 1.08278
[2024-03-28T14:49:22.420+03:00]: 1.08278
[2024-03-28T14:49:22.420+03:00]: 1.08278
[2024-03-28T14:49:22.420+03:00]: 1.08278
```

Comment: Где вывод вашего скрипта? Пересказывать не нужно - показывайте всю инфу прямо в вопросе. По сути вы же запрашиваете дневки "1D". Хотите более мелкий тайм-фрейм- задавайте к примеру "60" - это будет 1 час. И в целом вопрос должен быть оформлен так. Вот такие входные данные - я получаю то-то. А должен был получить то-то. Конкретный вывод скрипта, а не рассуждения-описания. Ссылка на тайм-фреймы https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Timeframes.html#timeframe-string-specifications "5M" - это 5 месяцев с точки зрения pinescript-а.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо за ответ. Сейчас дополню вопрос примерами вывода скрипта :)

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, за какой период эти данные. Напечатайте `print(len(dh))` что скажет. Может это все 5-минутки внутри дня? Но торги не идут в начале дня, поэтому все цифры одинаковые. Что в таком случае выводится, когда торги не идут, я не знаю. Может действительно high за этот день. А может за предыдущий. А может так совпало, что потом с началом торгов цена пошла вниз и начало дня совпало с high поэтому (а цена эта осталась с прошлого дня). Я бы попробовал нарисовать график того, что вы получаете. Может что-то понятнее станет.

Comment: dh[0] - high сегодня, dh[1] - high вчера и так далее. А причем тут 5 минутка, если в request.security() принудительно указан период D? Я новичок в pine, я использую v5, тут нет функции len :(

Comment: А, наверное я не до конца понимаю, как это всё работает. И что вы запрашиваете. Т.е. вы делаете одинаковый запрос с "D1", но выбрав при этом разные графики, на разные таймфреймы и периоды? Мне кажется вам нужно попробовать отрисовать получаемые данные, как в примерах в документации для request.security показано. Может на графике будет более понятно, что происходит?

Comment: Вы слишком все усложняете. Отбросьте все. Есть всего одна строка кода, которая должна при любом раскладе возвращать серию high/low свечей с периода 1D, насколько я понимаю, так как период 1D УКАЗАН В ЗАПРОСЕ ЯВНО. Но это работает только в том случае, если в терминале, где запущен скрипт, выбран период 1D. Это перестает работать, если выбрать более младший таймфрейм на том же инструменте, потому что серия dh/dl заполняется значениями HIGH сегодняшнего дня. Я написал в поддержку TW.

Comment: Я нарисовал plot по серии dh, и она рисуется по high дней. Просто видимо я туплю :D Ладно, большое Вам спасибо за попытку, но пусть мне отвечают из саппорта, в конце концов им уже уплочено было)

Comment: Это работает, но не так как я ожидал. В итоге я восхищусь PineScript, когда пойму это, но не сейчас :DDD

Comment: Потом расскажете, что и как. Интересно же )